# Formatting values fetched from dirty datastore

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-dirty

Is it possible to format data which is fetched from dirty? For example, 83647 to be formatted as 83,647. I have the following code for unformatted data:

```
db.on('load', function() {
  db.set('john', {completed: '83647'});
  console.log('John's completed tasks are: %s', db.get('john').completed);
});
```

Comment: hope this fiddle will help you .... http://jsfiddle.net/dKRGE/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) is what you are looking for..

example:

```
numeral(12345).format('0,0'); // -> 12,345
```